# Nginx - when tunnel the url redirects without port number

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, django, ssh-tunnel

My problem is very similar to this: [nginx proxy pass redirects ignore port](https://serverfault.com/questions/363159/nginx-proxy-pass-redirects-ignore-port)

I am using nginx 1.0.14.

I want to be able to ssh-tunnel into my Django website, so I can work remotely. I've tested a simple Django project on my personal computer, with very simple nginx configuration (starter, default). I tunnel and redirection returns with port number as part of the url. So I am sure this is not a Django problem. It's mainly my nginx configuration.

Here is the relevant part.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost 127.0.0.1;
    server_name_in_redirect off;

# location other services go here

location ~ /forum/(.*)$ {
    #rewrite ^(.*):(.*)/forum(.*)$ /$2 last;
    #rewrite ^(.*)$ http://localhost:8000/$1;
    #rewrite ^/forum(.*)$ $1 break;

    # the forum service runs as local, listens to 8000 port...
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
    proxy_redirect default;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

So what happen if I ssh-tunnel?

```
ssh -L 1111:192.168.1.165:80 username@server-address -N
```

then open the browser, `http://localhost:1111`, and when I login, or do anything that requires redirection, I get [http://localhost/forum/front-page](http://yahoo.com) instead of     [http://localhost:1111/froum/front-page](http://yahoo.com)

These links are wrong, nginx will complain (from the server side) they do not exist.

Internally, the service forum runs at `http://localhost:8000`

I've tried stuff like

```
proxy_set_header $host:$server_port;  # or
proxy_set_header $proxy_host:$proxy_port;  # or
proxy_set_header $host:$proxy_port;  # or
rewrite ^(.*):(.*)/forum(.*)$ /$2 last;
#rewrite ^/forum(.*)$ $1 break;
proxy_redirect http://localhost/ http://$host:$proxy_port;
```

The 2nd proxy_set_header shows a little progress. After pressing `submit`, I get a blank page, with the original url (http://localhost:1111/post and then I see the same url again).

Any idea how to resolve my problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I came up with a simple solution...as my own answer...

```
proxy_set_header Host $host;
```

`$host` should be replaced with `$http_host`, although I am not quite sure the meaning of either.

Comment: $host only prints the hostname, $http_host prints hostname:portnumber

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [proxy_redirect](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_redirect) It rewrites the host header of the response to prevent the problem you're facing. Setting it to default should do the trick.

Comment: I did have `proxy_redirect` to default. Please look at the first code snippet. It shows that I have those criteria. But they didn't solve my problem. I heard that my solution (posted as an answer) is dangerous.